# How to set local_listener to null upon creating database

Tags: oracle, installation

In Oracle, I am creating a database with a silent install using DBCA and a template. The template does not define `local_listener`.

`<initParam name="local_listener" value=""/>`

After the database is create, it has a value for `local_listener` = `LISTENER_dbname`. However, I don't want this parameter to have a value when it is created. How can I ensure that this parameter is created with a null value?

Comment: Why don't you want it to have a value?

Answer (score 1):

I tested specifying -initparams local_listener='' but the local_listener has been set anyways by specifying the empty string.

```
dbca -silent \
 -createDatabase \
 -templateName General_Purpose.dbc \
 -gdbName testdb \
 -sid testdb \
 -createAsContainerDatabase false \
 -SysPassword oracle \
 -SystemPassword oracle\
 -emConfiguration NONE \
 -datafileDestination /oradata \
 -storageType FS \
 -characterSet AL32UTF8 \
 -memoryPercentage 10 \
 -initparams local_listener=''
```

You might want to create a custom template referencing a .sql script with the command alter session set local_listener.

I'd only make that effort if in need to use it multiple times, though. If it is a one time thing, maybe you're better off setting local_listener manually.

Answer (score 0):

I know, it is an old question, but if anyone is still having this problem and finds it:

`dbca` parameter `-honorControlFileInitParam` works for us with an adapted template as described in the question